# Load yaml file using javascript and get the data in the yaml file

Tags: javascript, html, yaml

I am creating a function to load a yaml file via javascript and however I am stuck on how to get the data from the yaml file where I will subsequently use the data to fill up labels in my HTML page.

Here is my progress for the javascript so far:

```
<script>
// YAML file to Javascript object
    $.get( 'yaml/cars_loan.yaml', function( text ) {
        var obj = jsyaml.load( text );
        console.log( obj );
    });
</script>
```

*This is the updated correct codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the $.get() datatype parameter to be text. jsyaml needs yml type text data to load.